# How can I concatenate text to a filtered column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with google forms and google sheets. I'm trying to create a summary sheet that will automatically update as the form is being filled.

I've been able to pull the data from the other sheets using a FILTER function. Now I want to add a column that shows the name of a country to the filtered column. I tried using concatenate but it didn't work as well as I'd hoped. Can someone help me figure out how to solve this problem.

Please see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tC0FamTfLMRmBr-FmhtSTxPtJ6THIQHyfDKdSrQ-m2g/edit?usp=sharing) for an example of the problem.

Comment: I can't see the country names in the source sheets. Where are these located? Are they only in the sheet name? In such case, would you be open to using an Apps Script custom function?

Comment: I am open to using an Apps Script function. As long as it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is a very inelegant brute force way, but I think it works.  See Solution-GK in your sheet.

```
=QUERY({
   {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("Nigeria~",ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(NIGERIA!A:E,NIGERIA!C:C<TODAY(),NIGERIA!B:B="Charity Fundraiser")))),"~")),
                                         UNIQUE(FILTER(NIGERIA!A:E,NIGERIA!C:C<TODAY(),NIGERIA!B:B="Charity Fundraiser"))}; 
   {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("Sierra Leone~",ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER('SIERRA LEONE'!A:E,'SIERRA LEONE'!C:C<TODAY(),'SIERRA LEONE'!B:B="Charity Fundraiser")))),"~")),
                                              UNIQUE(FILTER('SIERRA LEONE'!A:E,'SIERRA LEONE'!C:C<TODAY(),'SIERRA LEONE'!B:B="Charity Fundraiser"))}},
  "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4, Col5 where Col2 is not null")
```

I've added a hard coded literal of the country name, repeated it the number of times needed for the matching data rows, and made it into the first column in your existing data array.  I repeat this for the second array you have for the second country.

I'm sure there are far more elegant ways to do this, so we'll see what else is proposed.  If you had a list somewhere in your sheet of your country names - ie. Nigeria and Sierra Leone, possibly many more - I'm sure an elegant solution would cycle through those names, pulling the name to build the concatenated data ranges, and also adding the name as the text for each row.

Without needing a list in the sheet, a little bit of code could find all of your tab names, and exclude the non data ones, eg. Solution Here and Summary, and process all of the rest as data.

Note: I'm not clear that you need your `UNIQUE` statements, unless you are expecting duplicates for some reason.  Also, the outer `QUERY` doesn't seem to be necessary - the inner `FILTERs` seem to do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an Apps Script [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting **Tools > Script editor**, and copy the following functions to the script (check inline comments for more details about the code):

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function SUMMARIZE_FUNDRAISING_EVENTS(sheetNames, ...ranges) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames = sheetNames.split(","); // Comma-separated string to array of sheet names
  const filteredData = sheetNames.map(sheetName => { // Iterate through each sheet name
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (sheet) { // Check if sheet exists with this name
      const sheetData = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues(); // Source sheet data
      const filteredData = sheetData.filter(rowData => {
        return rowData[1] === "Charity Fundraiser" && rowData[2] < new Date()
      }); // Filter data according to date and type of event
      filteredData.forEach(filteredRow => filteredRow.unshift(sheetName)); // Add sheet name to filtered data
      return filteredData;
    }  
  }).flat();
  return filteredData;
}
```

Once it is defined, you can use the function `SUMMARIZE_FUNDRAISING_EVENTS` the same you would any sheets built-in function. This function would accept a series of parameters:

- A comma-separated string with the names of the sheets whose data should be summarized (don't add blank spaces after the comma or similar).
- The different source ranges (in your case, `NIGERIA!A:E` and `'SIERRA LEONE'!A:E`).

Both of these are necessary, because, on the one side, specifying the source ranges as parameters makes sure that the function executes and updates the summarized data every time the source ranges are edited, and on the other side, when passed as parameters, these source ranges don't contain information about the sheet names, which the script will need when returning the summarized data.

Example of calling the function:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)